# Android SSL Connection Man in the middle attack

Tags: java, android, security, ssl

I am working on an app where at some point I need to retrieve the website title given the URL. The following code does that

```
InputStream response = null;
            try {
                response = new URL(urlString).openStream();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response);
                String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                title = responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf("<title>") + 7, responseBody.indexOf("</title>"));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                didWeGetTitle = true;
                CustomLogger.log("UrlDataExtractor: retrieveWebsiteTitleAndFavicon: Retrieve title: Error IOException. " + e,'e');
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The problem is that for certain web pages (For example CreditCheckTotal.com) IOException is being thrown. Here is the exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

It is my understanding that the reason this is happening is that SSL Certificate is not trusted. I was looking for a way to address this problem and came around a post that suggested to run the following code before establishing the connection.

```
private static void trustEveryone() {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }});
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }}}, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                    context.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now, from the post, it became obvious that this solution can pose a security threat because it creates a possibility of MIMA. Now, my question is, since the only point of my above-mentioned code is to grab the title of the webpage, is it a problem for me to just trust all the certificates?

Comment: Yes it's a problem because you don't know whether you have the title of the correct webpage at the correct server. Do not use this code.

Comment: EJP I am not sure what you mean? Could you provide a situation where this code might be harmful by just grabbing the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate validation is done to make sure that you are talking to the correct server, i.e. protect against man in the middle attacks. If you want to grab only the title of a web page and don't transfer any sensitive data the risk of disabling certificate validation can be considered acceptable, as long as you accept the risk that you get a different content (which might result in a different title) in case of a man in the middle attack.

Comment: I have not dealt with security issues too much at this point so what I am thinking right now might be totally wrong but here we go. I am ok with the fact that I might receive a different title if MIMA occurs but since my code is downloading the whole html file, is it possible for the downloaded html file to have some malicious code that might do some damage?

Comment: @Saik: If you access sites not fully controlled by you then you have to deal with possible unexpected content anyway. This is not a problem newly added with MITM attacks.